# store files in mongoDB withour GridFS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, filesystems, gridfs

I work on a web app developped with MEAN stack, I need to store files in mongoDB without calling GridFs since this later has weakness with little files, I have made many researchs but i always find GridFS.

Comment: You could use GridFS for just the big files and something else (directly embed into a document?) for the little files.

Answer (score 4):

MongoDB has a [Binary type](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/binary.html). It's very easy to use:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var mongo = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;
var Binary = mongo.Binary;

// Connection url
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

// Connect using MongoClient
MongoClient.connect(url).then(function (db) {
    var collection = db.collection('bins');

    return collection.insert({
        name: 'image2',
        // the constructor takes a Buffer
        bin: new Binary(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/img.jpg'))
    }).then(function () {
        console.log('inserted');
        db.close();
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Retrieve the stored file:

```
MongoClient.connect(url).then(function (db) {
    var collection = db.collection('bins');

    return collection.findOne({ name: 'image2' }).then(function (doc) {
        console.log(doc);

        fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/out.jpg', doc.bin.buffer);

        db.close();
    })
});
```

Usage of the Binary type can be implicit. This will create a binary field too:

```
collection.insert({
    name: 'image2',
    bin: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/img.jpg')
})
```

Keep in mind that MongoDB documents have a [16MB total size limit](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/).

Comment: Caution! be sure that your total document size doesn't exceed 16MB limit. It's MongoDB hard limit so just in case.

Comment: @Saleem Of course but OP seems to be aware of this limit, he/she discarded GridFS because of *weakness with little files*.

Comment: I agree. People with varying experience visit stack overflow to search for solution and often they misread without realizing tradeoffs. However, you have a good solution with better explanation, so thumbs up!

Comment: @Saleem I added a note about the limit, just in case.

Comment: Thank you very much!! it is the best solution in my case!